# simply bash script doesn't work

Tags: bash, echo

```
#!/bin/bash  
echo "hello"
```

I run this script and I have got only empty space why? I am sure my code is okay, so why don't show text's?

Comment: How are you running it? Can you show the exact command and output?

Comment: Change the interpreter to `#!/bin/bash -x` to see what is executing shell

Comment: Try running "which bash" to see if your bash is really in /bin/bash, it may be in /usr/bin/bash or elsewhere.

Comment: See if you have any unusual characters in the script itself: `od -c myscript.sh`

Comment: Can you try echo "hello" on terminal?

Answer (score 4):

please specify what the problem is.

**If your script doesn't run:**

For running scripts you should make it executable:

```
chmod +x script.sh
```

Another thing that you should know is about **SELINUX** you should make sure it is sat or not...and specify at which directory it is running?

please run this command and let me know:

```
ls -l scipt.sh
```

**IF `echo` command doesn't work:**

At first run it in your terminal and see the result...may be the command `echo` is removed or not...

try to run this bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello"
echo $?
```

and try this one:

```
#!/bin/bash          
STR="Hello World!"
echo $STR
```

And let me know about output.
 better to ask your question at [unix Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [superuser](https://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Execute the below commands in the terminal to troubleshoot.

- Check to see what shell you are on.

The below command would tell you your current shell.

```
echo $SHELL
```

- Once you confirm that make sure that you have the bash shell present
  in the /bin directory.

  /bin/bash 
  echo "hello"

Answer (score 1):

make sure u've already made your content to your script file. In some case, if u use some editor like vscode it has some option that won't save content to the file.If this is your case, u may change the option.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same puzzling issue when running my hello world script from a terminal window, using Ubuntu. I was editing the file using gedit, giving all permissions from the properties gedit functionality, and when running ./hello_world.sh, further chmoded to +x from a terminal window as well, it simply wouldn't show the result of my echo "Hello World" command.

Needless to say as I have been through all the above answers and all showed my script should have worked.

I simply solved it by editing the script using vim from a terminal window! Then chmod +x again just in case, ran the script and Hello World finally appeared!

But I don't know why it didn't work using the gedit edition;